# Typescript - classes which share method but are not derived from a shared base class

Tags: typescript

Basically my setup is
I have a library, which contains a bunch of classes A, B, ... , Z
All of these classes share a common method call foo, but none of them derive from a base class.

These methods accept an argument, data, which is of type AT, BT, ... , ZT

e.g.

```
class B {
   foo(data: BT)
}


class Q {
   foo(data: QT);
}
```

In my code, I have to do something very repetitive which boils down do creating a method which takes a class (e.g. A) and a data object (e.g. of type AT) and then calling foo on that class object with the data object.

In typescript, is there a nice way i can just have one helper function rather than having to write a bunch of boiler plate code

i.e. today I do

```
createA(data: AT): A {
   let a: A;
   a.foo(data);
   return a;
}

createB(data: BT): B {
   let b: B;
   b.foo(data);
   return b;
}

...

createZ(data: ZT): Z {
   let z: Z;
   z.foo(data);
   return z;
}
```

I want to be able to do

```
createObject<ClassType, ArgumentType>(data: ArgumentType): ClassType {
   let myObj: ClassType;
   myObj.foo(data);
   return myObj;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side note: code like `let b: B;` doesn't actually create an object of type `B`; at runtime, `b` will be `undefined` and you will have immediate problems trying to call its `foo()` method.  I am supposing/hoping that in your actual code you are actually constructing instances of `B` etc.  But that implies that you should be passing a class constructor to your `createObject()` function.  I'm ignoring that for the rest of the answer and will use your signature and implementation more or less as-is.  Be warned.

---

You can write your generic function like this:

```
function createObject<C extends { foo(a: A): void }, A>(data: A): C {
  let myObj: C = null!; // <-- this isn't initialized?
  myObj.foo(data);
  return myObj;
}
```

where we've used a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to tell the compiler that `C` will have a `foo()` method that takes an argument of type `A`.  You should then be able to call it:

```
declare const qt: QT;
const obj = createObject<Q, QT>(qt); // okay, type Q
```

Note that you are required here to manually specify the `C` and `A` type parameters when you call the function if you expect to see a strongly-typed output:

```
const oops = createObject(qt); //
// const oops: { foo(a: QT): void; }
```

If you want the compiler to *infer* the output type from the input type, then you need to give `createObject()` a call signature that tells the compiler every input-output mapping you care about:

```
type IOMap = [QT, Q] | [BT, B] // | ... | [ZT, Z];
type ClassType<A extends IOMap[0]> = Extract<IOMap, [A, any]>[1];

function createObject<A extends IOMap[0]>(data: A): ClassType<A>;
function createObject<C extends { foo(a: A): void }, A>(data: A): C {
  let myObj: C = null!; // <-- this isn't initialized?
  myObj.foo(data);
  return myObj;
}
```

That's a bit annoying to declare, but is easier to use:

```
const obj = createObject(qt); // okay
// const obj: Q
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgKlAvFA3lARgLigRigXwG4AoAYwBsBDAZ2tlWKigDMB7VgCgBNLhLt4ASlQFi+YhIo06ARQZM2nHn2wy4wtOPGhIUNUhEBHbHiJQJzAK4A7UsACWra1FIAnCLwgB5dACsIdgA8AMJQEAAewBDWXHRoihz8UACCgtgAbqz2XAQANCkAfNy8SanYoSiMUOQQwFAAtiA+vuUG1pbk5ACEhFAA9H1QgQC0w1DAABb2dNPWAOR19tb2DpTk9gBeEFwA-FWNzQB0CcqUgiRM7sCWrs4HfiTixFwBVO4uTtR1hsCqcCSkT51Vh+AxuDxRZoBYCBGT5NRFH7nfqDVgAa0oIGIAw+1i+UBBLT0kiBBNYYDoyHBnihdg4SJIOMBeOB5Oo2Hi7ESfzSUEy2V6T2slHqEGoYEopGgADEOuQALKUMBgJYAcwYVR00AAkl5FWADABtNTwgC6UAAPlBDfB8jBzTirYdnZbrQAtOD5N2mi7jcDQYJUWhwf2BZJhSLRWJQXX6w0ABlNBQMAFFIq5JTDY0r8obkvlKNYQEnDTgfRIFDY7I5nNTIX5oWGI1EYnRs2AE0niioUrzA9IQ5AwwVfVZbA4nC53DSG0FQhEW9HOZxSrz+Tl8PlkkVTtgylAKlUmDU6vciaFkO1Oj0UUNRuMpjNqPNFstVustrsjw0mn5jlzTnOb8rhuO5f18X0niYF4pHeZl8R+P5fXg4FQSpad638OkGVvdFMSqJlSUJVQJDEIA)

Comment: How can you create object of type `C` inside `createObject()`? When I do just `new C()` there I get error "'C' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Comment: My side note at the beginning talks about this; I’d expect that the function should take another parameter of type `new () => C` so you have a way to construct one.  But since the example code didn’t even try to make instances of any of the classes involved, I’m not sure what the OP is doing and I assume they have their own solution to that.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. And yup, end up passing in another parameter of type C.